# How can I get the browser and OS from an HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers

How can I tell what browser a user is using and what OS based on the HTTP request header in NodeJS?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily extract this information from the HTTP Request headers. There is a request header called 'User-Agent'.
Access this header from the request and you'll get  a string with information like the Browser Model, Platform(OS), geckoversion etc.

Comment: When I do this I get "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36". I'm using Chrome and I wouldn't expect Mozilla, AppleWebKit and Safari to be there.

Comment: Well, I hope you know how to read a user-age string. All those are not browser names. Here, Mozilla is the User-Agent Application, AppleWebkit is the rendering engine of the client, Windows NT 10.0 is the OS and Chrome 85 is the browser.

Comment: Also, it is not an easy task reading a UA-string and getting the information you want, So tou can use some UA-Decoders available online or refer to MDN Docs for clarity.